# python - apply Operation on multiple variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that this is a rather silly question and there are similar ones already answered, but they don't quite fit, so...
How can I perform the same operation on multiple variables in an efficient way, while "keeping" the individual variables?
example:

```
a = 3
b = 4
c = 5
a,b,c *= 2  #(obviously this does not work)
print(a,b,c)
```

What I want as the output in this scenario is 6, 8, 10. It is rather important that I can still use changed variables.

Thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: Any particular reason why you can't do it manually? i.e. `a *= 2`, etc

Comment: because in a file that is already over 3000 lines long it gets quite messy writing the same command ten times. And also quite inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy or python lambda function combined with map to do the same.

**Using numpy:**

```py
In [17]: import numpy as np

In [18]: a = 3
    ...: b = 4
    ...: c = 5
    ...:

In [19]: a,b,c = np.multiply([a, b, c], 2)

In [20]: a
Out[20]: 6

In [21]: b
Out[21]: 8

In [22]: c
Out[22]: 10
```

**Using lambda:**

```py
In [23]: a, b, c = list(map(lambda x: x*2, [a, b, c]))

In [24]: a
Out[24]: 12

In [25]: b
Out[25]: 16

In [26]: c
Out[26]: 20
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following generator expression:

```
a, b, c = 3, 4, 5
a, b, c = (2 * i for i in (a, b, c))
print(a, b, c)
# 6 8 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into Python's map function. The following link may be helpful:https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_map.asp

Answer (score 0):

Map is your friend here, but you also need to use 'implicit tuple unpacking':

```
>>> a = 3
>>> b = 4
>>> c = 5
>>> d, e, f = map(lambda x: x * 2, [a, b, c])
>>> d
6
>>> e
8
>>> f
10
```

This way you can get the changed values back without modifying the original values

Answer (score 0):

You can store them in a container, and then use `map` to apply one function on every element of the container
For example with a list:

```
def function_to_apply(element):
    return element*2

# Define variables and store them in a container
a,b,c = 1,2,3
container = (a,b,c)

# Apply the function on every element with map
container = tuple(map(function_to_apply, container))
a,b,c = container
```

This can also be done with **lambda functions** to avoid defining a new function every time

```
# Define variables and store them in a container
a,b,c = 1,2,3
container = (a,b,c)

# Apply the function on every element with map
container = tuple(map(lambda x: x*2, container))
a,b,c = container
```

If you have a really large set of variables and you want to retrieve them automatically without having to type each one of them like in `a,b,c = container`,  you can use *dict* to store them with names or *exec* function to assign them dynamically.

*`map` documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

`lambda` documentation: [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-lambda-expr](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-lambda-expr_)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use map to apply a function to every element of a list with a lambda function to perform your operation. Then use list unpacking to overwrite values in orginal variables.

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

a,b,c = list(map(lambda x: x*2, [a,b,c]))

print(a,b,c)

# prints: (2, 4, 6)
```

map returns a generator, that's why we need to explicit create the list to unpack.

Comment: a little bit of explanation of the code would help your answer stand out!